# Joomla AEC issue with Paypal, possibly IPN

Tags: joomla, paypal

I installed the Joomla AEC Version 1.0, Revision 5149.

I have set up plans and everything in this matter, if user clicks on the create an account system will ask user to select the plan. Then user clicks on buy now, she goes through Paypal, Purchase get made (Subscription with 3 days free trial) then user get redirected back to the site which all works fine.

My problem is user will see the message that says "Thank you for your registration. Our system will now await your payment. You will receive an e-mail once our system has processed your request. ". site will never get the clearance from Paypal. I havent put any custom custom URL or anything like that.

Also site is in the staging. so the URL starts with http://staging.domainanme.com
Not sure if this will cause an issue.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps when using a sandbox mode in PayPal you need to confirm the payment manually by going to the list with payments (on PayPal) selecting to right transaction and clicking on confirm button (if there's one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AEC it is quite simple with a Paypal Subscriptions processor. You just need to put in the email address of your account at:

```
Processors -> Paypal Subscritions -> Business ID
```

Not sure if that will be the same with 1.0 as this is based on 1.2.

If you have a valid account that's all you need. Of course make sure you have assigned the processor to your plan.

So if this all checks out one other thing you can try. If you were using the paypal account before with some other domain then switch to staging.domainname.com then you might want to try adding the `Alternate IPN Notification Domain`. Find this at:

```
Processors -> Paypal Subscritions ->Alternate IPN Notification Domain
```

In here put exactly http://staging.domainname.com

**UPDATE:**

The problem is Paypal communication then. First remove the `Alternate IPN Notification Domain` setting in AEC that I suggested. That was just for testing.

Either Paypal email is not confirmed so the communication fails or the communication can't be established.

Assuming you are using Paypal Standard, go to Paypal and login. Check in this order:

1. Click on `Profile`. Does the email have "unconfirmed" beside the email? If it does then that's your problem.
2. Go to `Profile -> My selling tools -> Instant payment notifications`. Click update on the far right. Enable it and add a new notification url. It should look like: `http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?option=com_acctexp&task=paypal_subscriptionnotification`

Just another thought. Paypal doesn't enable Paypal subscriptions when you sign up for Paypal Standard. I can't remember exactly when/how that was done but I remember that a separate step was needed. That could also be the cause of this issue.

Comment: The business ID is correct, also I tried to put the http://staging.domainname.com as an alternate IPN however still I cant get the Paypal IPN back. I even made the site live and tested it. Still the same issue. Any other suggestion?

Comment: You are THE man :) I wish I could give your answer more points. I hope you answer helps other people and you get keeping points for it. 
GO TOM :)